# Is it necessary to pass by reference explicitly?

Tags: php, variables, reference, pass-by-reference

for example `shuffle(&$array);`

is it a bad practice to leave out the `&` sign when passing argument to functions like this one? Because it's working without it too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 it is bad, in earlier versions I suppose on some sort of meta way it can help the next person to read the code, but it generally is not the best idea just because it doesn't really *do* anything and most people will be confused by its inclusion (why is this person doing that? I don't get it...). `&` is used only four times:

- Assigning a variable reference: `$a =& $b` (a references b)
- parameters: `function inc(&$b){$b++;}` (b will now increment outside of func)
- returns: `function &get_thing(){ static $thing; return $thing; }` (You can now modify the static value)
- Iterations: `foreach($var as $key=>&$val){$val++;}`

Comment: i don't see an `&` in the third one

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to pass it; it's implicitly understood to be a reference. The documentation for these types of functions show it merely to communicate the fact that this will not be copied, but referenced.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not bad practice.  In fact, it is *good* practice.

When arguments to functions are to be passed by reference, that should be specified in the function definition.  You can see that this is so in the [PHP manual page for `shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle).

Call-time pass-by-reference (as in, `shuffle(&$arr)`) is poor practice. It is deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and will raise a warning.  This is because it can cause all kinds of kooky problems if a function isn't *expecting* its argument to be a reference.